# Theorem that says a permutation can be achieved by swaps and flips

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $S$ is a string of binary numbers. So if $|S| = 4$, then the number of possible sequences is $2^4 = 16$. Suppose $S = 0000$. Is there a theorem that says that any of the $16$ possible sequences can be achieved by translations (e.g moving the first digit to the back, moving the first 2 digits to the back etc.)? and reversals (e.g. flipping $1$ to $0$ or $0$ to $1$) given any possible starting sequence?

Comment: Isn't every possible sequence obtained by (at most) 4 reversals?

Comment: @ArnaudD.: I guess this was a silly question then. What if you were only allowed translations and 1 reversal?

Comment: Then from $0000$ you can only reach the sequences that have at most one $1$ in them (such as $0010$).

Comment: If however you can only flip a particular bit (without a restriction on how often), then by conjugating that with the shifting you will be able to flip any bit, and so reach any bit string.